# Sharing a Repository Among Two Computers

Tags: git, github

I'm having a hard time grasping how I can accomplish the below task:

1. I have a git repository on **Computer1**
2. I push to a repository on GitHub
3. Now I am on **Computer2** that has zero footprint of this repository and I want the repository to also live on **Computer2**
4. I want to be able to work on this repository's code on both computers

I'm having a difficult time determining what exactly needs to happen.  For **Step 3**, I would think I'd do a **fetch** or a **pull**, but (unless I'm reading this wrong) that only seems to pull down new and updated files.  There could potentially be old files in that repository, but because **Computer2** has none of them I'd want them all (I guess an actual copy of the repository).

I wouldn't think I'd want to create a **branch** or **fork** the repository, because I'm not looking for 2 separate versions out there.

And as for *Step 4*, once the prior steps were complete I would think on each computer I'd just do a **pull** to get the updated files.

Is my understanding correct, and if not how am I to accomplish the above tasks?

Comment: You always have a copy of the repository, since this is what a DVCS is all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `clone` the github repository on Computer2.

From then on, when you're done doing work on a given computer, you'll need to `push` your changes to github (to update your online copy), and then when you arrive at the other computer, `pull` those changes from github to the local copy to update it.

```
Computer1 --push--> GitHub

Computer1           GitHub --clone--> Computer2
```

---

```
 changes
    |
    |
    v
Computer1 --push--> GitHub            Computer2

Computer1           GitHub --pull---> Computer2

                                       changes
                                          |
                                          |
                                          v
Computer1           GitHub <--push--- Computer2

Computer1 <--pull-- GitHub            Computer2
```

Answer (score 3):

First install git and then `clone` your repository with the url you get from github. Afterwards all you need to do is pull and push to keep the two in sync.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate:**

Clone from *Computer 1* to *Computer 2*.  Then, you can work between your two computers, pushing from 2 to 1 as if 1 was the master for 2.  When you're finally ready to push to GitHub, either computer can be used to push to GitHub, but default behavior makes it easier to do from computer 1.