# Share git repository via pendrive

Tags: eclipse, git

Although my question looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550730/sharing-a-repository-among-two-computers), instead of GitHub I use pendrive and I also have two backups. Well, let me describe it below.

I use Kepler with EGit and command line git and have local repo "L1" (with working set) and also remote bare repo "R1" on another disk partition on the same computer "C1". L1 is configured to push/pull to/from R1. Besides I made a bare clone "P" of R1 on a pendrive "PD" so P is configured to fetch from R1. On another computer "C2" I made a clone "R2" of P so R2 is configured to fetch/push form/to P and then checkout out project form R2 into Eclipse using repo "L2" (with working set), so L2 is configured to fetch/push form/to R2. It basically server to exchange changes between two computers with help of pendrive and having bare backups on both computers. It looks like this:

```
C1: {L1, R1}; PD: {P}; C2: {R2, L2};
```

It is configured like this:

```
L1 <--pull push--> R1 <--push fetch--> P <--push fetch--> R2 <--push pull--> L2
```

After sequence `commit(L1).push(R1)`, `P.fetch(R1)`, **`R2.fetch(P)`** git says R2 and P are up-to-date, however I made commit to L1 and definitely they should differ. Any thoughts what do I do wrong and how to make it actually work?

Comment: I don't understand why this complications, you don't have a LAN or you can't setup a connection instead of carrying a pendrive?

Comment: These computers are in different locations (like about 4km from each other), they don't share LAN and they have limited network connection. In fact it's not an option, thus the pendrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to synchronize all the repositories, but I had to get rid of `fetch`
and use only `push` command.

As to details:

- L1 (managed by Eclipse with EGit on C1) is configured to pull/push from/to R1
- R1 (managed by command line git on C1) is configured to push to P
- P configuration uses a trick and I'll explain it later
- R2 is configured to push to P
- L2 is configured to pull/push from/to R2

Now as to P configuration: as I said, it looks like `A.push(B)` works a bit different
than `B.fetch(A)` (both repos are bare). So when I push something to P (from R1 or from R2)
and want to synchronize with other remote (like R2 or R1), I perform push from P, but I simply
change remote URL just before push. For this purpose I prepared a bash script (`push-all.sh`)
that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=`cat $1.url`;
for f in *.git
do
    cd $f;
    echo "Setting URL to $url$f";   
    git remote set-url origin $url$f;
    git push;
    cd ..;
done;
```

Note that all my bare repositories have *.git at the end of directory name.

On this pendrive there are two files (could be more if needed) contaning paths to repos on
remote machines with extention *.url (could be anything actually):

```
$ cat c1.url
d:\my\path\on\c1\git\

$ cat c2.url
e:\another\path\on\c2\
```

On C1 and C2 under git urls I have another `push-all.sh` script, but a little simplier:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.git
do
    cd $f;
    git push;
    cd ..;
done;
```

So now, when I finish work on C1 I make sure pendrive is connected to the computer and it has
the same letter as in R1 configuration and I do:

```
$ cd /d/my/path/on/c1/git
$ ./push-all.sh
```

Now all my work is copied from R1 to P. Then, when I get to computer R2 I do:

```
$ cd /p/git-repo-on-pendrive
$ ./push-all c2
```

Then I pull from EGit and there are all my changes. When I finish work on C2 I do:

```
$ cd /e/another/path/on/c2
$ ./push-all
```

And when I get to C1 I do:

```
$ cd /q/git-repo-on-pendrive
$ ./push-all c1
```

and I do pull from EGit. All this solved my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `R1.push(P)` or `P.pull(R1)`.

There is no difference between `R1.push(P)` and `P.pull(R1)`, except that in the former, `push` has to be run in `R1` and hence `P` must be a remote in `R1`, while in the latter, `pull` has to be run from `P` and hence `R1` must be a remote in `P`.

`P` is currently not updated completely, you only fetched the changes, didn't merge them.

As for the LAN/limited network issues, you can try using bitbucket for private repository, github for public repos. Either should be available at both locations.

***EDIT***

I just realised that my typo costed OP a lot of debugging effort - I meant `P.pull(R1)` earlier and not `P.fetch(R1)` as stated. Really sorry for that. A `pull` can be thought of as `fetch`+`merge` in a single operation. In fact, that was the first line of my answer, use a `push` or `pull` - I had meant to ask you to use a `pull` and not do a `fetch`. Once again, really sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: As to `P.pull(R1)`, it means *fetch and merge*, but R1 and P are bare repositories. Does `merge` apply here? And in case of bare repositories: what is the difference between `R1.push(P)` and `P.fetch(R1)`? I probably still miss some git concepts...

Comment: Well I think you will need to merge your changes as well, fetch alone won't update. Also, there is no difference betwwen `R1.push(P)` and `P.fetch(R1)`, except that in the former, `push` has to be run in `R1` and hence `P` must be a remote in `R1`, while in the latter, `pull` has to be run from `P` and hence `R1` must be a remote in `P`.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation, I'll give it a try when I get to the other computer and return to this one.

Comment: After some playing around with this, I believe there must be some functional difference between `R1.push(P)` and `P.fetch(R1)`, but my knowledge as far as it concerns Git is not sufficient to catch that difference. Well, it seems that when performing push in both directions it actually works. In case of pushing in one direction and fetching from another I still got problems. Maybe due to some configuration problems. But I prepared an answer with solution that may be useful for someone in similar case as mine.

Comment: @Cromax I just realised that my typo costed you a lot of debugging effort - I meant `P.pull(R1)` in my earlier comment and not `P.fetch(R1)` as stated. Really sorry for that. A `pull` can be thought of as `fetch`+`merge` in a single operation. In fact, that was the first line on my answer, use a `push` or `pull`, I meant you to use a `pull` and not do a `fetch`. Once again, really sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: No problem, really, but does actually `pull` have any application in `bare` repository? There is no such thing a `merge` in bare repos, at least AFAIK. What I, experimentally, find out, is that R1.push(R2) differs (apparently) from R2.fetch(R1). Again please note these are `bare` repositories.